# How can I pass HTML form information to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, backend

Alright, so I am working on a button that when clicked will display information from my RESTAPI - all without refreshing/reloading the page.

How it will work:
HTML button calls javascript function onClick -> javascript makes call to my API and displays the given information from my API.

Now, my API requires a "bet" parameter; which is a integer. The user provides this in a HTML input form.

```
        <form>
            Bet<br>
            <input onchange="checkBet" value="0.00001" type="text" name="bet"><br>
            <button type="button" id="dicebutton" onclick="prepareRoll()" style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="Images/dice.png"> Roll dice!</button>
        </form>
```

So, assuming the user typed in a number in `<input onchange="checkBet" value="0.00001" type="text" name="bet"><br>`, how can I pass that to my javascript function `"prepareRoll()"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give id to the input tag and access the value of the input in the code.

```
<form>
        Bet<br>
        <input id="betField" onchange="checkBet" value="0.00001" type="text" name="bet"><br>
        <button type="button" id="dicebutton" onclick="prepareRoll()" style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="Images/dice.png"> Roll dice!</button>
    </form>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function prepareRoll(){
    var input = document.getElementById('betField')
    var bet = input.value;

    //Make API call
}
```

You can use jQuery library to make api call, it is quick and simple to use. If do not wish to use then you can still go with XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.previousElementSibling` to reference the previous element, `.value` to get element `.value`

```
<button type="button" id="dicebutton" onclick="prepareRoll(`${this.previousElementSibling.name}=${this.previousElementSibling.value}`)" style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="Images/dice.png"> Roll dice!</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get the element value by ID?

Comment: Yes. Though the `.previousElementSibling` of `<button>` element does not have an `id` set at `html` at Question. `this` should reference `#dicebutton` element at `onclick` event attribute function call. Adjust the value passed as parameter if needed; for example, from `"bet=1"` to expected value

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing the value in the function call try to get the value in the function like here.

```
function prepareRoll(){
     var value=$("input type=['text']").val()
     //write the remaining code.


}
```

Comment: Note, Question does not include `jquery`  tag